# use parameter from function in a js.match(/(^|\s)here-\S+/g)

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I got this to work as expected by hard-coding the class prefix directly into the `match()`:

```
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        removePrefixClass:function(classPrefix){
            $(this).removeClass(function(index, css){
                return(css.match(/(^|\s)notice-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I put the function parameter `classPrefix` inside the `match()`?

The usage in this case would be `$(this).removePrefixClass('notice-')` in order to remove any class that is named `notice-success`, `notice-error`, `notice-warning` so on and so forth...

I've seen some answers here where the use of `RegExp` is suggested. But can't seem to figure it out how to use it in my scenario.

Here is the part of the code where it's in use:
(`/*  ajax request*  /` > `.done` > `if` there's an existing `#notice`)

```
$(function(){
    $("form.ajax").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('form[id]').length){  //  make sure the form has a unique id
            let $form = $('form#'+$(this).attr('id'));  //  use this specific form
            let $formNotice = $form.find('#notice');  //  locate #notice element
        /*  ajax request  */
            submitAjax($form)  //  personal wrapper function that just returns an $.ajax({...})-object
            .done(function(data,statusText,jqXHR){
                if($formNotice.length){  //  update existing notice
/*-->  */           $formNotice.removePrefixClass('notice-');   // remove class that starts with "notice-"
                    $formNotice.prependClass('notice-'+data['type']);  //  add new `notice-`class to the beginning to make it work
                    $formNotice.find('p').html(data['msg']);  //  add response message
                } else {  //  set new #notice
                    $(setNotice(data['type'],data['msg'])).hide().prependTo($form).slideDown("slow");  //  personal function that returns the `notice-`-html-element
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log('fail : '+statusText);
            })
            .always(function(){
                console.log('always');
            });
        //
        } else {
            console.log('form is missing id');  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a RegExp object explicitly, like this:

```
removePrefixClass: function(classPrefix) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\s)' + classPrefix + '\S+', 'g');
  $(this).removeClass(function(index, css) {
    return(css.match(re) || []).join(' ');
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried it out, but the class isn't removed as expected... Is there anything else I should take into consideration?

Comment: Without seeing a full example of your working code it's hard to say

Comment: I'll provide the part of the code where it's used in a minute